# In postfix, how can I override catch all to keep one account's mail local?

Tags: email, postfix, mail-forwarding

To catch all mail sent to `myexample.com` and forward it to another address we use the following in `virtual`:

```
@myexample.com myexample@gmail.com
```

However, we would like to keep all mail sent locally to the user `root` on the server, and do not want to forward it anywhere. (It's okay not to forward any `root@myexample.com` mail from other sources as well)

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Your `/etc/postfix/virtual` should be

```
root@myexample.com       any_local_user
@myexample.com myexample@gmail.com
```

Comment: Now I get this: `... postfix/error[7714]: ...: to=<root@myexample.com>, orig_to=<root>, relay=none, delay=0.01, delays=0.01/0/0/0, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (User unknown in virtual alias table)`

Comment: can u post your postconf -n output?